# Extract value inside a multi-nested JSON Object with a "number" as a key name?

Tags: javascript, json, object, types

I'm trying to **get the title of the first song** in the JSON Object below but I have to go through **a number as a key name.**

Normally, we can do like this: `title = top100.content.rank.title` but it doesn't work with `title = top100.content.1.title` like the Object below.

My current solution is: `title = Object.values(Object.values(top10.data)[1])[0].title` which is very long and ugly. If you have a better way, please help me.

```
top100 = {
    "info": {
        "category": "Billboard",
        "chart": "HOT 100",
        "date": "2021-09-11",
        "source": "Billboard-API"
    },
    "content": {
        "1": {
            "rank": "1",
            "title": "Butter",
            "artist": "BTS",
            "weeks at no.1": "10",
            "last week": "7",
            "peak position": "1",
            "weeks on chart": "15",
            "detail": "up"
        },
        "2": {
            "rank": "2",
            "title": "Stay",
            "artist": "The Kid LAROI & Justin Bieber",
            "last week": "1",
            "peak position": "1",
            "weeks on chart": "8",
            "detail": "down"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What about title = top100.content['1'].title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the obj[key] syntax

```
top100['content'][1]['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access title of the first song in this way:

```
top100.content["1"].title
```